# From a django library can we overwrite only parts of a viewset instead of rewriting the viewset completely?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets, djoser

I am working with djoser and upon reading the documentation, I want to alter some parts of the code from Userviewset. 
I want to overwrite `def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` and customize it. For the get request, instead of returning all the fields of the model, I want to return only *Username* and *Profile Picture*.
I tried doing `from djoser.views import UserViewSet`. Then,

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    # from djoser docs which I want to update
    @action(["get", "put", "patch", "delete"], detail=False)
    def me(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_object = self.get_instance
        if request.method == "GET":
            return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif request.method == "PUT":
            return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif request.method == "PATCH":
            return self.partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        elif request.method == "DELETE":
            return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

But I wonder this would work since neither `retrieve` nor `get_instance` are mentioned.
Is there a shorter correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a different response for `GET /users/me` then you only need to change your serializer.

You can do that without even subclassing `UserViewSet`. In `UserViewSet.get_serializer_class` there's

```
      elif self.action == "me":
            return settings.SERIALIZERS.current_user
```

so assign a different serializer in djoser settings.

See [docs](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#serializers)

Answer (score 0):

Don't touch viewset, if you want to later data you want to return, redefine please serializer that uses djoser.
This is example of serializer

```
from djoser.serializers import UserSerializer
class CustomUserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_avatar(self, obj):
        return obj.profile.avatar.url if obj.profile.avatar else ""

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "avatar")
```

Then use this serializer in DJOSER settings

```
DJOSER = {
    "..."
    "SERIALIZERS":{
        'current_user': 'bingo.serializers.CustomUserSerializer',
    }
}
```